# Unable to create a Recovery disc in Sony Vaio computer complaing "not a supported disc type"

Tags: sony-vaio

I am trying to create a Recovery Disc in Sony Vaio through Vaio care. I have inserted the blank disc but it is complaining

```
"The disc in the drive is not blank or is not a supported disc type"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Sony Vaio care is confused with the Virtual CD drive I have installed. I disable the Virtual CD drive and restart the Vaio Care. It is not complaining anymore.